# how to warp texture in openGL? (Perspective correction?)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, perspective

I wanna make the OpenGL program can present images and warp the images presented.

Although I achieved image rendering using OpenGL, I don't know how to warp an image.

An warpable example I want is ([Reference](https://vimeo.com/394121978)):

But a picture I got is:

[image]

As I know, this problem is related to perspective correction mapping.

But I don't know about that well.

Here is my source code.

```
void imageRender(Shader initShader, Shader imgShader, char *path){

glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);

float positions = { 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
                    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 
                    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 
                    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

float vertices[] = {
    // positions                                 // colors           // texture coords
    position[0], position[1], position[2],   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
    position[3], position[4], position[5],   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    position[6], position[7], position[8],   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    position[9], position[10],position[11],  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
};
unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3
};

unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// position attribute 
//glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0); 
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// color attribute 
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

//texture attribute 
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);


FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFileType(path, 0);
if (format == -1){
    cerr << BOLDRED << "[ERROR] IMAGE_NOT_FOUND" << RESET << endl;
    exit(1);
}

if (format == FIF_UNKNOWN){
    cerr << BOLDRED << "[ERROR] UNKNOWN_IMAGE_FORMAT" << RESET << endl;
    format = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(path);
    if (!FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(format)){
        cerr << BOLDRED << "[ERROR] IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_READABLE" << RESET << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(format, path);
FIBITMAP *bitmap32;

int bitsPerPixel = FreeImage_GetBPP(bitmap);
bitmap32 = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(bitmap);
int imageWidth = FreeImage_GetWidth(bitmap32);
int imageHeight = FreeImage_GetHeight(bitmap32);

GLubyte *textureData = FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap32);

GLuint texture1;
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

initShader.use();
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

int initalTime = time(NULL);

while(1){

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    int timecal = time(NULL);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    if ((timecal - initalTime) > imageTime) // imageTime value is 10 
        break;
}

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glDeleteTextures(1, &texture1);// image
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);//image

FreeImage_Unload(bitmap32);
FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}

}
```

Shader code is like that

```
//shader.vs
#version 330 core 
layout(location = 1) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    Texcoord = texcoord; 
}

//shader.fs
#version 330 core 
in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D texture5;

void main()
{
    outColor = texture2D(texture5, Texcoord); 
}
```

How can I warp texture?

And then Is it correct to use position value to warp texture image?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with perspective projection. You draw a polygon with 4 vertices parallel to the XY plane of the view, but the polygon is not a quad! Change the x coordinate of the 1st vertex (0.5f -> 1.0f). Perspective projection works with [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).

In generalperspective projection is achieved by a [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) matrix. Of course you can define homogeneous vertices to inspect the behavior:

Define an attribute tuple with homogenous vertices (4 components):

```cpp
float vertices[] = {
    // positions                // colors           // texture coords
    1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f, 2.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
    1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
   -1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
   -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f, 2.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
};
```

Adapt the vertex specification and the vertex shader:

```cpp
// position attribute 
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// color attribute 
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(float), (void*)(4 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

//texture attribute 
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 9 * sizeof(float), (void*)(7 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
```

```c
#version 330 core 
layout(location = 1) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    Texcoord = texcoord; 
}
```

[image]

---

Another option to achieve the effect is, to a an Z component  to the geometry. e.g:

```cpp
float positions = { 1.0f,  1.0f,  0.5f, 
                    1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 
                   -1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f, 
                   -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f };
```

and to compute the `w` component dependent on `z` in the vertex shader (e.g. `w = z + 2.5`:

```c
#version 330 core 
layout(location = 1) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, position.z + 2.5);
    Texcoord = texcoord; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But my explanation might be not clear. The goal I want is like that [link](https://vimeo.com/394121978). I wanna make a function of example to the OpenGL program. please let me know how can I warp 4 vertexes without wrinkle effect?

Comment: @YangSsong Sorry that is to broad. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial. Stackoveflow can helps you with specific issues. I recommend to read [LeranOpenGL - Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera).

Comment: Okay.. thank you. But I read your reference link. Is that link related to a texture warp?

Comment: @YangSsong Your texture wrapping works. But you have a basic misunderstanding. You have to learn about perspective projection. (camera)

Comment: Note that there is also projective texture mapping, and texture coordinates can be homogenous 4D coords too, there is also the `textureProj` function families which does the perspective divide for you (and might happen directly in the TMU instead of the shaders). The effect seeked here can be achieved by either perspectively warping the quad (directly via homogeneous coords in the vertex data or via a projection or homography matrix), or by compensating for the distorted mapping via projective texture mapping.